# JDBC timeout with ResultSet am I doing it right?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a JDBC ResultSet that gives me a TimeOut after only a few thousand rows are processed.  I have a few million rows to process, so I'd like to tweak my program to avoid this, just not sure what needs to be tweaked.

Database table is indexed and returns data quickly using selection criteria, so I don't believe it is on the database side.  I'm returned 14 columns mixed between address columns and ints.  Not a lot of data.

I'm doing a connection.createStatement() and then building the SQL from there.  The answer might be I should use a prepared statement.

```
        Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String jobNameFilter = (Cli.getJobName() != null) ? " AND [JobName] = '" + Cli.getJobName() + "'" : "";
        String sortOrder = (Cli.isAscending()) ? "ASC" : "DESC";
        String orderByClause = Cli.isRandom() ? " ORDER BY [Randomizer] " + sortOrder + ",[RecordID] " + sortOrder : " ORDER BY [RecordID] " + sortOrder;
        String startingIdFilter = (Cli.getStartingId() != null) ? " AND [RecordId] > " + Cli.getStartingId() : "";
        String driverQuery = "SELECT [RecordID], [Column1] AS [TrackingID], [Address]" + ", [Suite] AS [AptSuiteOther], [City], [Building2Key]"
                + ", [ST] AS [State], [ZIPCode]" + ", [BusinessName], [ContactLastName], [Suite]" + ", [Phone], [EmailAddress]"
                + " FROM [Project].[TestSet] WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)"
                + " INNER JOIN [Project].[State] sttable ON sttable.[ST] = UPPER([Project].[TestSet].[ST]) AND [TerritoryFlag] = 0" + " WHERE [BuildingKey] = 0 " + jobNameFilter
                + startingIdFilter + " AND (([FirstResponse] IS NULL AND ([Building2Key] IS NULL OR [Building2Key] = 0)) OR ([Building2Key] > 0 AND [SecondResponse] IS NULL)) " + orderByClause;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(driverQuery);
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        logger.error("SQLException", e1);
    }

        try {
        while (rs.next()) {

            int recordId = rs.getInt("RecordID");
            // Process data
            numberProcessed++;

        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        logger.error("SQLException", sqle);
    }
```

I'm closing all the ResultSet, Connection and Statement in a finally statement at a different level also.

I'm not sure if I need to set the timeout to something higher, setFetchSize to something greater?  Trap timeout and create ResultSet again?

Change logic to only pull one row at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to profile your app to find out for sure, but I'm guessing that the "// Process data" part is the culprit. You're holding the connection open while process all of the rows.

I'd suggest that you read a batch of rows at a time, close the statement, and then process the batch. Then do a select for the next batch, rinse and repeat.

Selecting one row at a time would introduce a lot of overhead, so I wouldn't suggest doing that.

Also, make sure that you're using a connection pool, so that you don't actually have to build a new Connection each time. The pool will keep it open for you, and recycle it if it goes dead / times out.

Comment: I was not using a connection pool, since this was the only connection, but switched over to using a connection pool and still get the same "java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset" error.  I'd like to know if I should be setting something like setFetchSize, or add TOP ? to the SQL being run? (SQL Server 2008 DB)  Or if I just need to catch that exception and run the query again?  Seems wrong to capture the Connection reset error however.